# Change of logo half way through presentation?

Tags: beamer

I would like to ask the following question, please.
I am using Beamer for a presentation.
At the top right of each of my slides appears a logo.
However, I am looking for a possibility to exchange this logo half way through my talk as the university/institution changed.

I used the code

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
%\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(-0.03\textwidth,0.76\textheight)
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(0.92\textwidth,-0.15\textheight)
\hskip0.1cm\pgfuseimage{institute-logo}\hskip0.1cm
\end{textblock*}
}
```

In the meantime I managed to do:

I managed to do this (skipping the option to have the logo in the top right part of the frametitle)

```
    \newif\ifplacelogo % create a new conditional
    \placelogotrue % set it to true
    \logo{\ifplacelogo   \pgfputat{\pgfxy(-6.25,-0.25)}{\pgfbox[center,base] {\includegraphics[height=15pt,keepaspectratio]{Logos/logo1.pdf}%
    \hspace{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2cm-50pt}%
     \includegraphics[height=15pt,keepaspectratio]{Logos/logo2.pdf}}}
    \else  \pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.4,-0.25)}{\pgfbox[center,base]{\includegraphics[height=30pt,keepaspectratio]{Logos/main-blue-CMYK.pdf}}}
    \fi} % replace with your own command
```

But I encountered another challenge:
What do I do, if I want a slide without a logo? Currently I only have two options, false, true. How do I incorporate a third, please?
Okay, found it: local definition via \nologo \newcommand{\nologo}{\setbeamertemplate{logo}{}}

Thank you for your help and ideas.

Comment: Have you tried to override the definition of the pgfimage halfway through your presentation? Otherwise please make a complete MWE that shows how you define the image etc.

Comment: BTW: Can you have a look at your old answers? They seem to have perfectly fine answers, but you never accepted any of them.

Comment: Sorry, I should learn how to use this webpage! My apologies. But when I cannot make comments and ask, how can I ask a question without opening another questions?

Comment: maybe you want to read [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)