# Spurious shifting of headline when conditionally placing logo on beamer slide using \pgfputat

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I have a macro taken from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/324809/59521) that places a logo on all frames following `\placelogotrue` and on no frame following `\placelogofalse`. It largely works as intended, but it causes headline and foodline of the frames *with* the logo to be slightly shifted to the left, leaving some spurious whitespace (compare the upper image footline with the lower image headline in the pictures below):

[image: frame with logo]
[image: frame without logo]

Here's the code to reproduce:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Malmoe}
% graphics
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.pdf}

% TikZ/PGF
\usepackage{pgf}

% customization of beamer style
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% define logo
\newif\ifplacelogo
\placelogotrue
\logo{\ifplacelogo\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.1,7.72)}{\pgfbox[right,base]{%
            \includegraphics[height=7mm]{example-image-a}
    }}\fi}%

% define custom headline
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
    \leavevmode%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{section in head/foot}%
        \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hfil\insertsectionhead\hfil}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{subsection in head/foot}%
        \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hfil\insertsubsectionhead\hfil}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\placelogofalse
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Why is that? I would have expected `\pgfputat` not to alter spacing on the frame at all...

I'm compiling with LuaLaTeX Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020) on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets explore it by trial and error (Unfortunately I couldn't find the problem). First if we replace the `\pgfbox[right,base]{\includegraphics[height=7mm]{example-image-a}}` with a space   then same problem appears but without that space   it is fine:

```
\logo{\ifplacelogo\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.1,7.72)}{ }\fi}%
```

[image]

The output of the following code (`\pgfputat{ }`) is also similar to the above image:

```
\logo{\ifplacelogo\pgfputat{ }{}\fi}%
```

If we insert logo directly by `\includegraphic` then the situation will get worse:

```
\logo{\ifplacelogo\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.1,7.72)}{\includegraphics[height=7mm]{example-image-a}}\fi}%
```

[image]

One can also fix this white space by inserting `\hspace{-0.5mm}` before `\pgfbox` or `\pgfxy`:

```
\logo{\ifplacelogo\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.1,7.72)}{\hspace{-0.5mm}\pgfbox[right,base]{%
            \includegraphics[height=7mm]{example-image-a}
    }}\fi}%
```

or using `\makebox[0pt][r]{}` instead of `\pgfbox`

```
\logo{\ifplacelogo\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.1,7.72)}{\makebox[0pt][r]
{\includegraphics[height=7mm]{example-image-a}}}\fi}%
```

See also [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146098/108724) for `\llap` and `\rlap` and [this (not completely related) post.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56937/108724)

Answer (score 3):

Replace the `\logo` command by

```
\logo{\ifplacelogo\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.1,7.72)}{\llap{\includegraphics[height=7mm]{example-image-a}}}\fi}
```

I didn't check the source of the problem, which is probably related to `\pgfbox`.

[image]

Comment: FYI: `rlap` can be used if the logo is on the left. `llap` and `rlap` create boxes of zero width and place their content to the left and right of it, respectively, over***lap***ping anything that's already there.